# Unable to run .exe created in NetBeans(on 64-bit Windows 10) on 32-bit OS

Tags: java, deployment, compatibility

I have created .exe file using Native Packaging, using Inno (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php). 
NetBeans is installed on Windows 64-bit.
The .exe file runs on machine with same OS(64-bit), but when deployed doesn't run on 32-bit OS.

Comment: You can't run 64-bit programs in a 32-bit environment, in any language.This is a limitation of the OS.

Comment: If you can run a 64-bit application on an OS it is a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey How can I create 32 -bit .exe file in netbeans installed on 64-bit OS?

Comment: I would ask them in their support group after first checking if this question has been asked before http://www.jrsoftware.org/newsgroups.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above issue, I copied the program from 64-bit Windows to 32-bit Windows and generated EXE using **Netbeans on 32-bit Windows** and then installed it on 32-bit system.